# Geb test: couldn't select option with text or value (tried several options)

Tags: jquery, geb

This is a problem that has me very confused and frustrated, and I hope that someone can help me.  I am working a Geb test that hits a select box that hits a State list.  I am running the test against a local xml database mockup.  I have set the value for State equal to a value (in this case 102722) that is both in my xml database and in Firebug via a table of State values that my colleagues have already load.  So I know that the value is the same in both places - I've double-checked this many times.   In the example, I've written it a total of 4 different ways and still the Geb selector returns this error on every one.    I've done everything I know how to do or look at, and would really cherish some help with this.  Thank you so much.

|  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: couldn't select option with text or value: 102722

Form items:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <label id="Country-label" class="toplabel" for="Country">Country<span class="required-indicator">*</span></label>
    <g:select name="Country" id="Country" from="${stuff.here....}" class="form-control" required="" optionKey="id" value="${stuff.here}" aria-labelledby="Country-label"/>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <label id="State-label" class="toplabel" for=State>State<span id="StateAsterisk" class="required-indicator">*</span></label>
    <g:select name="State" id="State" from="${[]}" class="form-control" optionKey="id" value="${stuff.here}" noSelection="['null':'']" aria-labelledby="State-label"/>
</div>
```

Geb test with selectors:

```
$('#Country').value(100225)
$('.div.col-sm-3').find('select', name: "Country").value(100225)
$('#State').value(102722)
$("form").State(102722)
$('.div.col-sm-2').find('select', name: "State").value(102722)
$('div.col-sm-2').find('select', name: "State").value(102722)
```

Rendered HTML from Firebug:

```
<select id="State" class="form-control" aria-labelledby="State-label" name="State">
<option value="null"></option>
<option value="102722">Alabama</option>
```

Comment: should also mention that I've inserted waitFor(x seconds) to see if it would hit those, and that didn't help.

Comment: Your selectors look right to me. What do `$('div.col-sm-2').find('select', name: "State").find('option')*.text()` and `$('div.col-sm-2').find('select', name: "State").find('option')*.attr('value')` return?

Comment: they always return one of these:   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: couldn't select option with text or value: 102722 (or whatever value I put in there).   I've taken great care to double-check that I 've matched the values the same from Firebug and the test xml db mockup I use.    :)There's a mismatch somewhere - but there is only one state table in the db that I'm using so I don't know what else it could be...

Comment: They should never return a `-`, they should return a list, it might be empty but it will always be a list. Are you sure that you don't have more than one `select` with that name in the page? What does `$('div.col-sm-2').find('select', name: "State").size()` return?

Comment: how do I run a statement like that?   Just let Geb run and it will tell me in the output?

Comment: Just `println()` it and it should show up in the grails test report.

Comment: that statement returned value of 0 - what does that mean?

Comment: That your navigator does not match the `select` element that you are trying to select.

Comment: Is it a selector problem or the value itself not matching up?   Or do I have an internal config problem somewhere that I'm not aware of?

Comment: There is no value to match because your selector returns an empty navigator. I would say that it's a selector problem but based on the information you gave I'm unable to say what exactly it is. You're simply not selecting that `select` named `Size` for some reason.

Comment: I tried it the other standard ways too. straight from the geb books and they didn't hit it either:   $('#State').value(102722)
$("form").State(102722)

Comment: I won't be able to help any more, you need to verify why your selectors don't work. What do `$("div").size()` and `$("div.col-sm-2").size()` return?

Comment: not sure why any of those <div> ones didn't work; as they've worked for me in previous tests.  I was able to find out what values were actually returning when I used $('#State).value() instead - and they were returning values that were very different than what I expected.  Just loaded them into my testing xml and matched the selectors to them and that worked OK.